# Random strings in my url's for all navigation

Tags: url, path

I have simple links such as:

```
 href="{path='PCP/alliance_blog/'}"
```

and the result in the url bar will be:

```
example.com/PCP/Index#.UkryCGTXhvk
```

^ What is the deal with the "#.xxxxxx" code being generated here? Other sites I've worked on and built out do not have this issue. Admittedly this site is absolutely enormous compared to them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using AddThis on your site?

You can disable the "click tracking" that they add to URLs by following instructions on the [AddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381252-click-tracking#disabling) site.

If you're not using AddThis, I'd imagine you're using another service that does something similar.